# Как перестать отслеживать изменения файла уже добавленного в индекс

Tags: git

Клонирую репозиторий,, в нем мне нужно поменять `build.gradle` специфичным образом под мою систему, поэтому не нужно чтобы это отправилось в коммит. Для этого, я добавляю файл в `.git/info/exclude` потом делаю изменения и `git status` показывает, что файл изменен. Тогда я попытался удалить его из индекса: `git rm --cached`, но теперь опасаюсь, что в коммит отправится сам факт удаления. Как правильно прекратить отслеживать изменения в этом файле?

Comment: Через git status не можешь убедиться, что в коммит отправиться сам факт удаления?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535767/4854931

Comment: `в коммит отправится сам факт удаления` – если добавите изменение — отправится.

Comment: @Alex78191 убедился, отправится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это команда работает с индексом, так что в индекс и так все добавлено.